# Semantic-ui preset checkbox state

Tags: checkbox, semantic-ui

I've got a simple semantic-ui checkbox as follows:

```
<div id="del-checkbox-div" class="ui checkbox">
   <input type="hidden" value="0" name="delete_show_data" onclick=check()>
   <input id="delete-data-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" name="delete_show_data" onclick=check()>
   <label for="delete-data-checkbox">Delete show data</label>
</div>
```

I'd like to preset its state on page load. Per the [semantic-ui documentation](https://1.semantic-ui.com/modules/checkbox.html#behavior) I should be able to do the following in javascript:

`jQuery('#del-checkbox-div').checkbox('behavior', 'uncheck');`

However, I'm getting the following error:

`TypeError: jQuery(...).checkbox is not a function`

Can someone clue me in as to what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So the basic problem was I forgot to enqueue semantic.min.js. Notwithstanding the proper way to set/unset a checkbox is:

`jQuery('#del-checkbox-div').checkbox('check');`

or

`jQuery('#del-checkbox-div').checkbox('uncheck');`